# Can we project onto the intersection of the $\ell_1$ ball and a subspace?

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces, computational-geometry, projection

Let $V$ be a proper nontrivial closed vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^N$, and consider the [$1$-ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) $B_1=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^N\, |\, \|x\|_1\leq \gamma\}$ for some $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}_{++}$.

> Is there a closed-form for computing the projection onto $B_1\cap V$?

I know this can be solved numerically, but I'm curious about a closed-form solution. For the $2$-ball $B_2=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^N\,|\,\|x\|_2\leq\gamma\}$, it follows from [section 7 in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.00585.pdf) that $P_{B_2\cap V}=P_{B_2}\circ P_V$. Are y'all aware of any similar results for the $1$-norm (or *any* other norms, for that matter)?

[This graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xwhvaossjt) might he helpful for visualization for the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: You can find the general terms for decomposing of the Proximal Map [here](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2013/file/98dce83da57b0395e163467c9dae521b-Paper.pdf)

Comment: @iarbel84 Thanks! Although I don't think these properties apply for the [indicator functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(convex_analysis)) of $B_1$ and $V$ :(